# Dugite/isomorphic-git in electron behind a proxy

Tags: node.js, git, electron, isomorphic-git

I'm writing an electron app that has to clone and pull repositories every once in a while and it works well. However, it fails behind a corporate authenticated (basic or digest) proxy. As I understand electron can faciliate the Chromium proxy features but [dugite](https://github.com/desktop/dugite), the git library I'm using, is running in the main process and tries to connect directly to the git repository.
Is there some way I can use the proxy for dugite?

**EDIT:** I did some additional research and figured out that [node doesn't handle proxy connections for you](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15620). Proxy settings are only honoured if they are faciliated inside the renderer view and only if they use the browser window's methods like fetch. Therefore I also tried [isomorphic-git](https://github.com/isomorphic-git/isomorphic-git) as a dugite replacement in the renderer process but that - for some unknown reason - didn't work either.

Accepted solutions must be code that can be handled inside the electron app.

Comment: So I don't suppose https://github.com/desktop/dugite/blob/46adebec7529216d54a09d77ed25ac17dc89e27f/docs/environment-variables.md#installation or https://github.com/request/request#controlling-proxy-behaviour-using-environment-variables would help here?

Comment: no, that doesn't do. I'm down to fetching the repos with electron's net module and unpacking them. Not quite git but it does get the job done for now.

Comment: So setting HTTP_PROXY is ignored? are you sure you are using the correct proxy URL?

Comment: using these env vars would entail storing auth strings there too if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: try it *without* authentication: `HTTP_PROXY=http://usr/to/your/proxy` (no `user:password@` part in it). Same for HTTPS_PROXY (except you still reference an http URL, not https, for your proxy URL). If the server had already done authentication to the proxy, your own process might reuse it.

Comment: You might be on to something. I checked process.env again to see whether the vars have been set correctly but they weren't set in the first place. Something funny going on in Electron. I actually did try those two before but it didn't work. Well, if they were not set it might answer some questions. I need to find out why I can't set them in the main process. They do appear in the renderer if I set them on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass `HTTP_PROXY` to `GitProcess.exec()`:

```
const options = {
  env: {
    'GIT_HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'dugite/2.12.0',
    'GIT_TRACE': '1',
    'GIT_CURL_VERBOSE': '1',
    'HTTP_PROXY': '[protocol://][user[:password]@]proxyhost[:port]'
  },
  processCallback: (process: ChildProcess) => {
    byline(process.stderr).on('data', (chunk: string) => {
      // read line from progress and convert to percentage
    })
  }
}

const result = await GitProcess.exec([ 'pull', 'origin' ], path, options)
```

Or, you can exec `git config http.proxy [protocol://][user[:password]@]proxyhost[:port]` in your repository, that will configure http proxy for repository scope (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpproxy)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have moved on for now, not offering that functionality in my app. The corporate network added further hurdles. Wasn't worth the effort.